# Why does my nav bar add menu items in a vertical fashion?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, nav

I'm learning to work with Bootstrap, I made a menu, but the menu items get added in the right side, vertically, instead of the left side, horizontally. Help me identify my mistake.

Html file:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Register</title>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default " id="navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class = "navbar-header">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" id="text">Brand</a>
                </div>
                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav" >
                    <li><a href="" id="text"> Home <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" id="text">Team</a></li>
                <!--    <a href="" id="text">Gallery</a>
                    <a href="" id="text">Partners</a>
                    <a href="" id="text">News</a>
                    <a href="" id="text">Contact us</a>
                    <a href="" id="text">Register</a> -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>  

        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.css:

```
#navbar{
    /*back ground color*/
    background-color: #4311dd
}
/*change color to white*/
#text{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

The webpage I see,

[image]

Help me find where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Try setting li elements `display: inline-block;`. By default lists are vertical

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap you using?

Comment: @becks tried it, still the same

Comment: @hanif it's Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.2

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are leaving out important components i.e. stuff that's designed to be part of the Bootstrap navbar. Include those components back in and everything will show up as intended.

Bootstrap 4 is designed to be mobile first.

So, if you leave out the `navbar-toggler` components, then you get what you see because on mobile devices the navigation is stacked vertically.

Use this sample code as a template:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

P.S. The most recent version of Bootstrap 4 is **beta 3**. Beta 3 did introduce a few breaking changes as opposed to beta 2. (although none of them affect the navbar components)

Comment: For more information on Bootstrap navbar, please see here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score -1):

You should add `navbar-expand-lg` class on `<nav>` and `mr-auto` in `ul` like following way:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-lg " id="navbar">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" id="text">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto" >
        <li><a href="" id="text"> Home <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" id="text">Team</a></li>
    <!--    <a href="" id="text">Gallery</a>
        <a href="" id="text">Partners</a>
        <a href="" id="text">News</a>
        <a href="" id="text">Contact us</a>
        <a href="" id="text">Register</a> -->
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```